# What is this encoding type of text?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

i'm just compiling a project and i got a tutorial which have many characters. i asked author and he only said that it was a type of encoding. i can't paste all of them so here is one of them:

> S2jDtG5nIMSRw7puZw==

json file:

```
{"dethi":{"id":23,"key":0,"time":900,"type_of_exam":1,"type_of_answer":1,"merge_round":1,"question_number_cross_round":0,"background":"\/files\/user.png","style_answer":[],"number_question":30,"point":300,"list_round":[{"round_id":72,"round_name":"Vòng 1","round_name_2":1,"number_question":10,"point":100,"time":300,"is_countdown":0,"exam_type":1,"answer_type":2,"point_round":0,"listQuestRound":[{"id":6458,"q":"VGhhbmggdHJhIGdpYW8gdGjDtG5nIMSRxrDhu51uZyBi4buZIGPDsyDEkcO6bmcgbMOgIGPGoSBxdWFuIGPDsyB0aOG6qW0gcXV54buBbiBxdXkgxJHhu4tuaCBjw6FjIMSRb+G6oW4gxJHGsOG7nW5nIGPhuqVtIMSRaSwgxJHGsOG7nW5nIMSRaSBt4buZdCBjaGnhu4F1LCBuxqFpIGPhuqVtIGThu6tuZywgY+G6pW0gxJHhu5csIGPhuqVtIHF1YXkgxJHhuqd1IHhlLCBs4bqvcCDEkeG6t3QgYsOhbyBoaeG7h3UgxJHGsOG7nW5nIGLhu5kgdGh14buZYyDEkeG7i2EgcGjGsMahbmcgcXXhuqNuIGzDvSBoYXkga2jDtG5nPw==","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":1,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"S2jDtG5nIMSRw7puZw=="},{"idx":1,"text":"xJDDum5n"}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6457,"q":"Q8ahIHF1YW4gQ+G6o25oIHPDoXQgZ2lhbyB0aMO0bmcgxJHGsOG7nW5nIGLhu5kgY8OzIMSRw7puZyBsw6AgY8ahIHF1YW4gY8OzIHRo4bqpbSBxdXnhu4FuIHF1eSDEkeG7i25oIGPDoWMgxJFv4bqhbiDEkcaw4budbmcgY+G6pW0gxJFpLCDEkcaw4budbmcgxJFpIG3hu5l0IGNoaeG7gXUsIG7GoWkgY+G6pW0gZOG7q25nLCBj4bqlbSDEkeG7lywgY+G6pW0gcXVheSDEkeG6p3UgeGUsIGzhuq9wIMSR4bq3dCBiw6FvIGhp4buHdSDEkcaw4budbmcgYuG7mSB0aHXhu5ljIMSR4buLYSBwaMawxqFuZyBxdeG6o24gbMO9IGhheSBraMO0bmc\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":2,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"xJDDum5n"},{"idx":1,"text":"S2jDtG5nIMSRw7puZw=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6456,"q":"4bumeSBiYW4gbmjDom4gZMOibiBj4bqlcCB04buJbmggY8OzIMSRw7puZyBsw6AgY8ahIHF1YW4gY8OzIHRo4bqpbSBxdXnhu4FuIHF1eSDEkeG7i25oIGPDoWMgxJFv4bqhbiDEkcaw4budbmcgY+G6pW0gxJFpLCDEkcaw4budbmcgxJFpIG3hu5l0IGNoaeG7gXUsIG7GoWkgY+G6pW0gZOG7q25nLCBj4bqlbSDEkeG7lywgY+G6pW0gcXVheSDEkeG6p3UgeGUsIGzhuq9wIMSR4bq3dCBiw6FvIGhp4buHdSDEkcaw4budbmcgYuG7mSB0aHXhu5ljIMSR4buLYSBwaMawxqFuZyBxdeG6o24gbMO9IGhheSBraMO0bmc\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":3,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"xJDDum5n"},{"idx":1,"text":"S2jDtG5nIMSRw7puZw=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6455,"q":"Q8ahIHF1YW4gcXXhuqNuIGzDvSBnaWFvIHRow7RuZyB24bqtbiB04bqjaSBjw7MgxJHDum5nIGzDoCBjxqEgcXVhbiBjw7MgdGjhuqltIHF1eeG7gW4gcXV5IMSR4buLbmggY8OhYyDEkW\/huqFuIMSRxrDhu51uZyBj4bqlbSDEkWksIMSRxrDhu51uZyDEkWkgbeG7mXQgY2hp4buBdSwgbsahaSBj4bqlbSBk4burbmcsIGPhuqVtIMSR4buXLCBj4bqlbSBxdWF5IMSR4bqndSB4ZSwgbOG6r3AgxJHhurd0IGLDoW8gaGnhu4d1IMSRxrDhu51uZyBi4buZIHRodeG7mWMgxJHhu4thIHBoxrDGoW5nIHF14bqjbiBsw70gaGF5IGtow7RuZz8=","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":4,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"xJDDum5n"},{"idx":1,"text":"S2jDtG5nIMSRw7puZw=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6454,"q":"TmfGsOG7nWkgxJFp4buBdSBraGnhu4NuLCBuZ8aw4budaSBuZ+G7k2kgdHLDqm4geGUgxJHhuqFwIG3DoXkgY8OzIHBo4bqjaSDEkeG7mWkgbcWpIGLhuqNvIGhp4buDbSBjw7MgY8OgaSBxdWFpIMSRw7puZyBxdXkgY8OhY2gga2hpIHRoYW0gZ2lhIMSRxrDhu51uZyBi4buZIGhheSB0aMO0bmc\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":5,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[2],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"VMO5eSB0csaw4budbmcgaOG7o3A="},{"idx":1,"text":"S2jDtG5n"},{"idx":2,"text":"Q8Oz"}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6453,"q":"TmfGsOG7nWkgxJFp4buBdSBraGnhu4NuIHhlIG3DtCB0w7QgaGFpIGLDoW5oLCB4ZSBn4bqvbiBtw6F5IHPhu60gZOG7pW5nIMO0LCDEkWnhu4duIHRob+G6oWkgZGkgxJHhu5luZyBjw7MgdmkgcGjhuqFtIHF1eSB04bqvYyBnaWFvIHRow7RuZyBraMO0bmc\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":6,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"a2jDtG5nIHZpIHBo4bqhbQ=="},{"idx":1,"text":"Q8OzIHZpIHBo4bqhbQ=="},{"idx":2,"text":"VMO5eSB0csaw4budbmcgaOG7o3A="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6748,"q":"Qmnhu4NuIG7DoG8gYsOhbyBoaeG7h3UgZ2lhbyBuaGF1IHbhu5tpIMSRxrDhu51uZyDGsHUgdGnDqm4\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":2,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":7,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDEuIMKg"},{"idx":1,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDIu"},{"idx":2,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDMu"}],"image":"\/files\/gthd2019\/images\/2018\/01\/image-15155691100.png?v=1546792205"},{"id":6747,"q":"Qmnhu4NuIG7DoG8gYsOhbyBoaeG7h3UgZ2lhbyBuaGF1IHbhu5tpIMSRxrDhu51uZyBraMO0bmcgxrB1IHRpw6puPw==","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":2,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":8,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[2],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDEgdsOgIDIu"},{"idx":1,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDIgdsOgIDMu"},{"idx":2,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDEgdsOgIDMu"}],"image":"\/files\/gthd2019\/images\/2018\/01\/image-15155690710.png?v=1546792205"},{"id":6746,"q":"Qmnhu4NuIG7DoG8gYsOhbyBoaeG7h3UgY2jhu4kgZOG6q24geGUgxJFpIHRyw6puIMSRxrDhu51uZyBuw6B5IMSRxrDhu6NjIHF1eeG7gW4gxrB1IHRpw6puIHF1YSBuxqFpIGdpYW8gbmhhdT\/CoA==","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":2,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":9,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[2],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDEgdsOgIGJp4buDbiAy"},{"idx":1,"text":"Q+G6oyBiYSBiaeG7g24u"},{"idx":2,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDEgdsOgIGJp4buDbiAz"}],"image":"\/files\/gthd2019\/images\/2018\/01\/image-15155690250.png?v=1546792205"},{"id":6745,"q":"Qmnhu4NuIG7DoG8gYsOhbyBoaeG7h3UgY2jhu4kgZOG6q24geGUgxJFpIHRyw6puIMSRxrDhu51uZyBuw6B5IMSRxrDhu6NjIHF1eeG7gW4gxrB1IHRpw6puIHF1YSBuxqFpIGdpYW8gbmhhdT8=","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":2,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":30,"point":10,"ordinal":10,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDEgdsOgIDMu"},{"idx":1,"text":"Qmnhu4NuIDEgdsOgIDIu"},{"idx":2,"text":"Q+G6oyBiYSBiaeG7g24u"},{"idx":3,"text":"Ymnhu4NuIDIgdsOgIDMu"}],"image":"\/files\/gthd2019\/images\/2018\/01\/image-15155689300.png?v=1546792205"}]},{"round_id":73,"round_name":"Vòng 2","round_name_2":2,"number_question":15,"point":150,"time":420,"is_countdown":0,"exam_type":1,"answer_type":2,"point_round":0,"listQuestRound":[{"id":6141,"q":"TmfGsOG7nWkgxJFp4buBdSBraGnhu4NuIHhlIMSR4bqhcCDEkWnhu4duIHRoYW0gZ2lhIGdpYW8gdGjDtG5nIGtow7RuZyDEkWkgYsOqbiBwaOG6o2kgdGhlbyBjaGnhu4F1IGPhu6dhIG3DrG5oLCDEkWkga2jDtG5nIMSRw7puZyBwaOG6p24gxJHGsOG7nW5nIHF1eSDEkeG7i25oIGLhu4sgcGjhuqF0IHRp4buBbiB04bur4oCmIMSR4bq\/buKApi4\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":11,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[3],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"VOG7qyA4MC4wMDAgxJHhur9uIDEwMC4wMDAgxJHhu5NuZy4="},{"idx":1,"text":"VOG7qyAxMDAuMDAwIMSR4bq\/biAyMDAuMDAwIMSR4buTbmcu"},{"idx":2,"text":"VOG7qyA2MC4wMDAgxJHhur9uIDgwLjAwMCDEkeG7k25nLg=="},{"idx":3,"text":"VOG7qyA1MC4wMDAgxJHhur9uIDYwLjAwMCDEkeG7k25nLg=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6140,"q":"S2hpIMSRaeG7gXUga2hp4buDbiB4ZSDEkeG6oXAgxJFp4buHbiBz4butIGThu6VuZyDDtCBob+G6t2MgxJFp4buHbiB0aG\/huqFpIHPhur0gYuG7iyBwaOG6oXQgdGnhu4FuIGJhbyBuaGnDqnU\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":12,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"VOG7qyA1MC4wMDAgxJHhur9uIDYwLjAwMCDEkeG7k25nLg=="},{"idx":1,"text":"VOG7qyAzMC4wMDAgxJHhur9uIDQwLjAwMCDEkeG7k25nLg=="},{"idx":2,"text":"VOG7qyA2MC4wMDAgxJHhur9uIDcwLjAwMCDEkeG7k25nLg=="},{"idx":3,"text":"VOG7qyA0MC4wMDAgxJHhur9uIDUwLjAwMCDEkeG7k25nLg=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6139,"q":"xJBp4buBdSBraGnhu4NuIHhlIMSR4bqhcCDEkWnhu4duIGNo4bqheSBkw6BuIGjDoG5nIG5nYW5nIHThu6sgMyAoYmEpIHhlIHRy4bufIGzDqm4gdGjDrCBi4buLIHBo4bqhdCB0aeG7gW4gdOG7q+KApiDEkeG6v27igKY\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":13,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"VOG7qyAzMC4wMDAgxJHhu5NuZyDEkeG6v24gNTAuMDAwIMSR4buTbmcu"},{"idx":1,"text":"VOG7qyA1MC4wMDAgxJHhu5NuZyDEkeG6v24gNjAuMDAwIMSR4buTbmcu"},{"idx":2,"text":"VOG7qyAzMC4wMDAgxJHhu5NuZyDEkeG6v24gNDAuMDAwIMSR4buTbmcu"},{"idx":3,"text":"VOG7qyA0MC4wMDAgxJHhu5NuZyDEkeG6v24gNTAuMDAwIMSR4buTbmcu"}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6138,"q":"VMO5bmcgxJFhbmcgxJFp4buBdSBraGnhu4NuIHhlIG3DoXkgxJFp4buHbiB0aGFtIGdpYSBnaWFvIHRow7RuZyB2w6AgY8OzIMSRaeG7h24gdGhv4bqhaSwgVMO5bmcgxJHDoyBnaeG6o20gdOG7kWMgxJHhu5kgdsOgIHLDunQgxJFp4buHbiB0aG\/huqFpIHJhIG5naGUsIGjDoG5oIMSR4buZbmcgY+G7p2EgVMO5bmcgY8OzIHZpIHBo4bqhbSBMdeG6rXQgZ2lhbyB0aMO0bmcgxJHGsOG7nW5nIGLhu5kgaGF5IGtow7RuZz8=","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":14,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"S2jDtG5nLg=="},{"idx":1,"text":"Q8OzLg=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6096,"q":"S2hpIG11YSB4ZSBtw6F5IMSRaeG7h24gKGxv4bqhaSB4ZSBuaOG6rXAga2jhuql1KSBuZ8aw4budaSBkw6JuIGPhuqduIHnDqnUgY+G6p3UgY+G7rWEgaMOgbmcgY3VuZyBj4bqlcCBsb+G6oWkgZ2nhuqV5IHThu50gbsOgbyBkxrDhu5tpIMSRw6J5Pw0KDQrCoA==","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":15,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"R2nhuqV5IGtoYWkgxJHEg25nIGvDrSB4ZS4="},{"idx":1,"text":"R2nhuqV5IGNo4bupbmcgbmjhuq1uIGNo4bqldCBsxrDhu6NuZyBhbiB0b8OgbiBr4bu5IHRodeG6rXQgdsOgIGLhuqNvIHbhu4cgbcO0aSB0csaw4budbmcgeGUgY8ahIGdp4bubaSBuaOG6rXAga2jhuql1Lg=="},{"idx":2,"text":"UGhp4bq\/dSBraeG7g20gdHJhIGvEqSB0aHXhuq10IHh14bqldCB4xrDhu59uZy4="},{"idx":3,"text":"QuG6o28gaGnhu4NtIGTDoG5oIGNobyB4ZSBtw6F5IMSRaeG7h24u"}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6095,"q":"VuG7m2kgeGUgxJHhuqFwIMSRaeG7h24gY2jhuqF5IHBpbiwgY8OzIHRo4buDIHPhu60gZOG7pW5nIGxv4bqhaSBwaW4ga2jDoWMgY2hvIHhlIGPhu6dhIGLhuqFuIHNhdSBraGkgcGluIGLhu4sgaOG7j25nIGtow7RuZz8=","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":16,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"Q8OzIHRo4buDIHRoYXkgcGluIG5oxrBuZyBwaOG6o2kgY8O5bmcgbG\/huqFpIHbhu5tpIHBpbiDEkWFuZyBz4butIGThu6VuZy4="},{"idx":1,"text":"Q8OzIHRo4buDIHRoYXkgbeG7jWkgbG\/huqFpIHBpbi4="},{"idx":2,"text":"S2jDtG5nIHRo4buDIHRoYXkgcGluLCBwaOG6o2kgdGhheSB4ZSBt4bubaS4="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6094,"q":"xJDhu4MgxJHhuqNtIGLhuqNvIHbhuq1uIGjDoG5oIHhlIMSR4bqhcCDEkWnhu4duLCB4ZSBtw6F5IMSRaeG7h24gYW4gdG\/DoG4sIG5nxrDhu51pIHPhu60gZOG7pW5nIGPhuqduIGzGsHUgw70gxJFp4buBdSBnw6w\/DQoNCsKg","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":17,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"VGjGsOG7nW5nIHh1ecOqbiBraeG7g20gdHJhIGPDoWMgYuG7mSBwaOG6rW4gdGF5IGdhLCBo4buHIHRo4buRbmcgcGhhbmgsIMSR4buZbmcgY8ahLg=="},{"idx":1,"text":"Q+G6oyAyIMO9IMSR4buBdSDEkcO6bmc="},{"idx":2,"text":"S2jDtG5nIGNo4bufIHF1w6Egbmhp4buBdSBuZ8aw4budaSBob+G6t2MgY2jhu58gaMOgbmcgcXXDoSBu4bq3bmcu"}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6093,"q":"VGhlbyBi4bqhbiwgbmjhu69uZyBow6BuaCB2aSBuw6BvIHNhdSDEkcOieSBj4bqnbiB0csOhbmggxJHhu4MgxJHhuqNtIGLhuqNvIMSRaeG7gXUga2hp4buDbiB4ZSDEkeG6oXAgxJFp4buHbiwgeGUgbcOheSDEkWnhu4duIHRoYW0gZ2lhIGdpYW8gdGjDtG5nIG3hu5l0IGPDoWNoIGFuIHRvw6BuPw==","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":18,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"VOG6pXQgY+G6oyBjw6FjIHBoxrDGoW5nIMOhbiDEkcawYSByYSDEkeG7gXUgxJHDum5nLg=="},{"idx":1,"text":"Q2jhu58gdGhlbyAwMiAoaGFpKSBuZ8aw4budaSB0csOqbiB4ZSwgY2jhu58gaMOgbmcgY+G7k25nIGvhu4FuaC4="},{"idx":2,"text":"VOG7sSDDvSB0aGF5IMSR4buVaSB0aGnhur90IGvhur8gY+G7p2EgeGUu"},{"idx":3,"text":"S2jDtG5nIMSR4buZaSBtxakgYuG6o28gaGnhu4NtIGTDoG5oIGNobyBuZ8aw4budaSDEkWkgbcO0IHTDtCwgeGUgbcOheS4="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6092,"q":"VGhlbyBi4bqhbiwgbmjhu69uZyB2aeG7h2MgbMOgbSBuw6BvIHNhdSDEkcOieSBuw6puIHRo4buxYyBoaeG7h24gxJHhu4MgxJHhuqNtIGLhuqNvIMSRaeG7gXUga2hp4buDbiB4ZSDEkeG6oXAgxJFp4buHbiwgeGUgbcOheSDEkWnhu4duIHRoYW0gZ2lhIGdpYW8gdGjDtG5nIG3hu5l0IGPDoWNoIGFuIHRvw6BuPw==","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":19,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[2],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"VOG6pXQgY+G6oyBjw6FjIHBoxrDGoW5nIMOhbiDEkeG7gXUgxJHDum5nLg=="},{"idx":1,"text":"VOG7sSDDvSB0aGF5IMSR4buVaSB0aGnhur90IGvhur8gY+G7p2EgeGUu"},{"idx":2,"text":"VuG6t24gZ2EgdOG7qyB04burLCB0csOhbmggdHLGsOG7nW5nIGjhu6NwIHbhurduIGdhIMSR4buZdCBuZ+G7mXQu"},{"idx":3,"text":"S2jDtG5nIMSR4buZaSBtxakgYuG6o28gaGnhu4NtIGTDoG5oIGNobyBuZ8aw4budaSDEkWkgbcO0IHTDtCwgeGUgbcOheS4="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6091,"q":"S2hpIMSRaeG7gXUga2hp4buDbiB4ZSDEkeG6oXAgxJFp4buHbiwgeGUgbcOheSDEkWnhu4duIMSRaSBxdWEgxJHGsOG7nW5nIG5n4bqtcCBuxrDhu5tjIGPhuqduIGNow7ogw70gxJFp4buBdSBnw6w\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":20,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"VOG6r3Qgbmd14buTbiDEkWnhu4duLCBkw7luZyBiw6BuIMSR4bqhcCDEkeG7gyBkaSBjaHV54buDbi4="},{"idx":1,"text":"Q+G7qSDEkWkgcXVhIG5oxrAgYsOsbmggdGjGsOG7nW5nLg=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6090,"q":"TsOqbiBz4butIGThu6VuZyBwaW4sIOG6r2MgcXV5IGPhu6dhIHhlIMSR4bqhcCDEkWnhu4duLCB4ZSBtw6F5IMSRaeG7h24gbmjGsCB0aOG6vyBuw6BvIMSR4buDIGR1eSB0csOsIMSRxrDhu6NjIGNo4bqldCBsxrDhu6NuZyBjxaluZyBuaMawIHR14buVaSB0aOG7jSBj4bunYSBwaW4gPw0KDQrCoA==","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":21,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[2],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"U+G6oWMgYuG6pXQgY+G7qSBsw7pjIG7DoG8u"},{"idx":1,"text":"THXDtG4gbHXDtG4gc+G6oWMgxJHhuqd5IHBpbiBob+G6t2Mg4bqvYyBxdXku"},{"idx":2,"text":"RMO5bmcgaOG6v3QgZHVuZyBsxrDhu6NuZyBj4bunYSBwaW4sIOG6r2MgcXV5IHLhu5NpIHPhuqFjOyBt4buXaSBs4bqnbiBz4bqhYyB0aMOsIHPhuqFjIMSR4bqneS4="},{"idx":3,"text":"Q+G6oyAzIMO9IMSR4buBdSBzYWk="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6089,"q":"S2hpIHRoYW0gZ2lhIGdpYW8gdGjDtG5nIGLhurFuZyB4ZSDEkeG6oXAgxJFp4buHbiwgbmfGsOG7nWkgxJFp4buBdSBraGnhu4NuIHBoxrDGoW5nIHRp4buHbiBwaOG6o2kgY8OzIGdp4bqleSBwaMOpcCBsw6FpIHhlLCDEkcO6bmcgaGF5IHNhaT8=","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":22,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"U2FpLg=="},{"idx":1,"text":"xJDDum5nLg=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6063,"q":"TmfGsOG7nWkgbmfhu5NpIHBow61hIHNhdSB4ZSBtw6F5IMSRaeG7h24gY8OzIGPhuqduIHBo4bqjaSDEkeG7mWkgbcWpIGLhuqNvIGhp4buDbSBkw6BuaCBjaG8gbmfGsOG7nWkgxJFpIG3DtCB0w7QsIHhlIG3DoXkgaGF5IGtow7RuZz8=","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":23,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"Q8OzLg=="},{"idx":1,"text":"S2jDtG5nLg=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6062,"q":"TmfGsOG7nWkgxJFp4buBdSBraGnhu4NuIHhlIMSR4bqhcCDEkWnhu4duLCB4ZSBtw6F5IMSRaeG7h24gcGjhuqNpIMSR4buZaSBtxakgYuG6o28gaGnhu4NtIGPDsyBjw6BpIHF1YWkgxJHDum5nIHF1eSBjw6FjaCBraGkgbsOgbz8=","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":24,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[2],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"S2hpIMSRaSB0csOqbiBjw6FjIHR1eeG6v24gxJHGsOG7nW5nIHF14buRYyBs4buZLg=="},{"idx":1,"text":"S2hpIMSRaSB0csOqbiBjw6FjIHR1eeG6v24gxJHGsOG7nW5nIHRyb25nIHRow6BuaCBwaOG7kSwgdGjhu4sgeMOjLCB0aOG7iyB0cuG6pW4u"},{"idx":2,"text":"S2hpIHRoYW0gZ2lhIGdpYW8gdGjDtG5nLg=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"},{"id":6061,"q":"xJDhu4MgxJHhuqNtIGLhuqNvIGFuIHRvw6BuIGtoaSB0aGFtIGdpYSBnaWFvIHRow7RuZywgbmfGsOG7nWkgbMOhaSB4ZSDEkeG6oXAgxJFp4buHbiwgeGUgbcOheSDEkWnhu4duIGPhuqduIHRo4buxYyBoaeG7h24gbmjGsCB0aOG6vyBuw6BvPw==","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":1,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"","time":28,"point":10,"ordinal":25,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"xJBpIHRyw6puIHbhu4lhIGjDqCBiw6puIHBo4bqjaS4="},{"idx":1,"text":"xJDhu5lpIG3FqSBi4bqjbyBoaeG7g20sIGPDoGkgcXVhaSDEkcO6bmcgY8OhY2gsIHF14bqnbiDDoW8gZ+G7jW4gZ8Ogbmc="},{"idx":2,"text":"QnXDtG5nIGPhuqMgaGFpIHRheSBob+G6t2MgxJFpIHhlIGLhurFuZyBt4buZdCBiw6FuaC4="},{"idx":3,"text":"U+G7rSBk4bulbmcgw7QsIMSRaeG7h24gdGhv4bqhaSBkaSDEkeG7mW5nLg=="}],"image":"?v=1546792205"}]},{"round_id":74,"round_name":"Vòng 3","round_name_2":3,"number_question":5,"point":50,"time":180,"is_countdown":0,"exam_type":1,"answer_type":2,"point_round":0,"listQuestRound":[{"id":6631,"q":"VHJvbmcgdMOsbmggaHXhu5FuZyBkxrDhu5tpIMSRw6J5LCB4ZSBjb24gY8OzIGNo4bqlcCBow6BuaCDEkcO6bmcgcXV5IHThuq9jIGdpYW8gdGjDtG5nIGtow7RuZz8=","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":3,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/2018\/01\/image-15154848850.mp4","time":36,"point":10,"ordinal":26,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"Q8Oz"},{"idx":1,"text":"S2jDtG5n"}],"image":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/thumbnails_video.png?v=1546792205"},{"id":6630,"q":"VHJvbmcgdHLGsOG7nW5nIGjhu6NwIHNhdSDEkcOieSwgeGUgY29uIGPDsyDEkeG7lyDEkcO6bmcgcXV5IHThuq9jIGdpYW8gdGjDtG5nIGtow7RuZz8=","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":3,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/2018\/01\/image-15154848500.mp4","time":36,"point":10,"ordinal":27,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[0],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"Q8Oz"},{"idx":1,"text":"S2jDtG5n"}],"image":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/thumbnails_video.png?v=1546792205"},{"id":6629,"q":"VHJvbmcgdHLGsOG7nW5nIGjhu6NwIHNhdSDEkcOieSwgeGUgbcO0IHTDtCBjw7MgxJHhu5cgxJHDum5nIHF1eSB04bqvYyBnaWFvIHRow7RuZyBraMO0bmc\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":3,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/2018\/01\/image-15154848210.mp4","time":36,"point":10,"ordinal":28,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"S2jDtG5n"},{"idx":1,"text":"Q8Oz"}],"image":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/thumbnails_video.png?v=1546792205"},{"id":6628,"q":"VHJvbmcgdHLGsOG7nW5nIGjhu6NwIHNhdSDEkcOieSwgeGUgbsOgbyDEkeG7lyDEkcO6bmcgcXV5IHThuq9jIGdpYW8gdGjDtG5nPw==","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":3,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/2018\/01\/image-15154847920.mp4","time":36,"point":10,"ordinal":29,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[2],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"WGUgY29uIHbDoCB4ZSB04bqjaQ=="},{"idx":1,"text":"WGUgdOG6o2kgdsOgIG3DtCB0w7Q="},{"idx":2,"text":"WGUgY29uIHbDoCBtw7QgdMO0"}],"image":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/thumbnails_video.png?v=1546792205"},{"id":6627,"q":"VHJvbmcgdMOsbmggaHXhu5FuZyBzYXUgxJHDonksIHRoZW8gdGjhu6kgdOG7sSwgeGUgY29uIGPDsyBjaOG6pXAgaMOgbmggxJHDum5nIHF1eSB04bqvYyBnaWFvIHRow7RuZyBraMO0bmc\/","dis":1,"play_type":4,"play_name":"Trắc nghiệm thường","type":3,"point_type":1,"audio":"","video":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/2018\/01\/image-15154847490.mp4","time":36,"point":10,"ordinal":30,"minuspoint":0,"idxTrue":[1],"ans":[{"idx":0,"text":"S2jDtG5n"},{"idx":1,"text":"Q8Oz"}],"image":"\/files\/gthd2019\/videos\/thumbnails_video.png?v=1546792205"}]}],"clone_id":141}}
```

that is a Vietnamese project (Author is Vietnamese and me too) so i think it is a UTF-8 text. Can u guys help me please.

P/s: sorry for my bad English

Comment: I'm glad the problem is resolved.  Please "upvote" either/both responses, and "accept" one of them.  That way, your question will be marked "resolved", for the benefit of others with the same question.

Comment: @paulsm4 The user can't upvote; 15 reputation points are needed for upvote privilege.

Comment: But the OP can - and should - "accept" when he gets a chance.  It's good practice ... and it will earn him some extra "reputation points" ;)

Comment: @paulms4 I know. So, let's guide them by showing what to do when someone answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (Van Duck, accepting is not mandatory. But if an answer helped you, it is the right thing to do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.

In Javascript, you can decode it (from base64 ASCII into binary) with the function [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

EXAMPLE:

```
var qData = atob(data.dethi.list_round[0].listQuestRound[0].q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a base64 encoded string.
The decoded out put is may be `Không đúng.`

you can convert it by using php function `base64_decode().`

For online convert visit https://www.base64decode.org/